# ftl @spring.message - handle NoSuchMessageException

Tags: spring, properties, model

I have the .ftl page where i put values from locale property files like so :

```
<div id="hiddenDiv">
    <@spring.message "${MyKey}.Popup"/>
</div>
```

The problem is that in some property files, i have the key MyKeyValue.Popup, but in others i don't. (namely the **en.properties** file)

And when spring tries to generate the model in english, it doesn't find that key in **en.properties** file.

Is there a way to handle that exception ? I have to handle it. I can't just put all of the possible keys into that property file. There are too many of them.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use this macro instead of the @spring.message :

<@spring.messageText "code", "Default message"/>

This doesn't throw an exception because it has a default value.

Hope this helps someone.